# How can I run all Tests classes in Project by TestNG?

Tags: testng

How can I run all Tests and all Classes in Project by TestNG suite if there are a lot of tests in one Class?
My suite xml code:

```
<suite name="Common Suite">
  <test name="Tests">
    <classes>
       <class name="package1.Class1"/>
       <class name="package2.Class2" />
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```

Class1 include 6 tests and CLass2 include 3 tests. When i run TestNG suite only first test in Class1 and first test in Class2 execute, other ignored. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parallel thread count is missing

```
 <suite name="Suite" parallel="methods" thread-count="4">
```